# Morse Sard Theorem

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

I'm reading the Morse-Sard's theorem in the book Differential Topology by Hirsch, and I wonder if anyone has a paper on the theorem with more details? I'm not proving it for manifolds, just open sets in $R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at "Differential Topology" by Guillemin and Pollack.